# How can I load SVG in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, vector

I'm trying to load SVG code into a WordPress page. 
So I finally have what I want set up in JSfiddle. 
There's some HTML and CSS.

But how would I go about loading this in a WordPress page. Initially I added the CSS to my child theme and simply pasted the html code inside the editor, but that didn't work. I've tried iframing it and a few other things, but my technical knowledge is too limited.

Would anyone know a solution?

First time asking a question here. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

**Code**:

```css
.hover_group:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#projectsvg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 77%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#projectsvg svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure id="projectsvg">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    //set your background image
<image width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="https://s1.thcdn.com/design-assets/images/nintendo/en/carousel/10881668/large/10881668-3.jpg">
</image>
<image id="estaca" width="120" height="120" xlink:href="https://portuguesewithcarla.com/temp/estaca.png" x="860" y="250" />
<g class="hover_group" opacity="0">
<a xlink:href="http://ptwithcarla.com">
<text x="760" y="380" font-size="40">NÍVEL UM</text>
<rect x="860" y="250" opacity="0.3" fill="#FFFFFF" width="120" height="120"></rect>
</a>
</g>
<g class="hover_group" opacity="0">
<a xlink:href="http://ptwithcarla.com">
<text x="960" y="680" font-size="40">NÍVEL DOIS</text>
<rect x="922" y="654.1" opacity="0.3" fill="#FFFFFF" width="64.6" height="300.8"></rect>

</a>
</g>

  <image id="animal" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="https://media.giphy.com/media/182TlvsqrfvlH5dnFm/giphy.gif" x="25" y="550">

  
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#animal"
           attributeName="x" 
           from="600"
           to="1100" 
           dur="6s"
           begin="0s"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="rect-anim"/>

</svg>
</figure>
```

Essentially it's code equivalent to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/wgh52j39/

Comment: Did you try this? http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=47

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

1. Allow uploading any SVG as an image through the media uploader ba adding this to your functions.php or a plugin:

```
/**
 1. Allow SVG files to be uploaded via Media Uploader
 */
    add_filter( 'upload_mimes', function( $mime_types ) {
        $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
        return $mime_types;
    }, 1, 1 );

    add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function( $mime, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );
        if ( in_array( $wp_filetype['ext'], [ 'svg' ] ) ) {
            $mime['ext']  = true;
            $mime['type'] = true;
        }
        return $mime;
    }, 10, 4 );
```

This may be a security concern if you have admins/authors for your site that are not aware of what they're doing, as SVGs may also contain unwanted code.

2. I can only tell for gutenberg editor, but if I add a custom HTML block and paste SVG code in there, it works for me. Not sure about the classic editor.
3. Upload the SVG manually via FTP/SFTP/SSH onto your server and link it like

```
<img src="https://yourdomain/the/folder/you/used/filename.svg">
```

4. To complete the list, even if it's not appropriate in your case but for small icon SVGs, you can encode the complete svg into CSS as background image ie via https://www.urlencoder.org/:

```css
.icon-heart { display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23dd0000%22%20d%3D%22M21.3%2C3.3c-2.5-2.1-6.1-1.7-8.4%2C0.6L12%2C4.8l-0.9-0.9C8.9%2C1.6%2C5.2%2C1.2%2C2.7%2C3.3c-2.8%2C2.4-3%2C6.7-0.4%2C9.4l8.7%2C9%20c0.6%2C0.6%2C1.5%2C0.6%2C2%2C0l8.7-9C24.3%2C10%2C24.1%2C5.7%2C21.3%2C3.3L21.3%2C3.3z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E); }
```

```html
<span class="icon-heart"></span>
```